# Phonegap project not working

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to execute the simple `Phonegap` example in `eclipse`, but it shows error as the application is doing too much work on its main thread.
Following is my code,

```
import org.apache.cordova.Config;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Test extends CordovaActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try:
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 10000);

Comment: it's the code of default cordova app except the last line should be commented. and do not post the same question twice in 2h of time just changing the title (in your other question the last line is commented as it should be)

Answer (score 1):

When you load url try to load it inside `Runnable` as below

```
this.cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

       super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }

});
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You are loading your main index file twice, maybe that's the problem.